# Setting anchor link color for single page applications with SammyJS

Tags: anchor, single-page-application, sammy.js

I have the following as my navigation structure in my SammyJS app.

```
<div id="sidebar-left" class="col-lg-2 col-sm-1">

                <input type="text" id="txt-search-items" class="search hidden-sm" placeholder="Search..." />

                <div class="nav-collapse sidebar-nav collapse navbar-collapse bs-navbar-collapse">
                    <ul class="nav nav-tabs nav-stacked main-menu">
                        <li class="parent">
                            <a href="#/link1"><i class="fa fa-dashboard"></i><span class="hidden-sm">Link 1</span></a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="parent">
                            <a class="dropmenu" href="#link2"><i class="fa fa-list-ul"></i><span class="hidden-sm">Link 2</span></a>
                            <ul class="child">
                                <li><a class="submenu" href="#/link2/sublink"><i class="fa fa-eye"></i><span class="hidden-sm">Sub Link</span></a></li>
                                </ul>
                        </li>
                        <li class="parent">
                            <a class="dropmenu" href="#link3"><i class="fa fa-archive"></i><span class="hidden-sm">Link 3</span></a>
                            <ul class="child">
                                <li><a class="submenu" href="#/link3/sublink1"><i class="fa fa-eye"></i><span class="hidden-sm">Sublink 1</span></a></li>
                                <li><a class="submenu" href="#/link3/sublink2"><i class="fa fa-eye"></i><span class="hidden-sm">Sublink 2</span></a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                        <li class="parent">
                            <a class="dropmenu" href="#/link4"><i class="fa fa-user"></i><span class="hidden-sm">Link 4</span></a>
                            <ul class="child">
                                <li><a class="submenu" href="#/link4/sublink1"><i class="fa fa-eye"></i><span class="hidden-sm">Sublink 1</span></a></li>
                                <li><a class="submenu" href="#/link4/sublink2"><i class="fa fa-eye"></i><span class="hidden-sm">Sublink 2</span></a></li>
                                <li><a class="submenu" href="#/link4/sublink3"><i class="fa fa-eye"></i><span class="hidden-sm">Sublink 3</span></a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                        <li class="parent">
                            <a class="dropmenu" href="#/administration"><i class="fa fa-cogs"></i><span class="hidden-sm">Link 5</span></a>
                            <ul class="child">
                                <li><a class="submenu" href="#/link5/sublink1"><i class="fa fa-eye"></i><span class="hidden-sm">Sublink 1</span></a></li>
                                <li><a class="submenu" href="#/link5/sublink2"><i class="fa fa-eye"></i><span class="hidden-sm">Sublink 2</span></a></li>
                                <li><a class="submenu" href="#/link5/sublink3"><i class="fa fa-eye"></i><span class="hidden-sm">Sublink 3</span></a></li>
                                <li><a class="submenu" href="#/link5/sublink4"><i class="fa fa-eye"></i><span class="hidden-sm">Sublink 4</span></a></li>
                                <li><a class="submenu" href="#/link5/sublink5"><i class="fa fa-eye"></i><span class="hidden-sm">Sublink 5</span></a></li>
                                <li><a class="submenu" href="#/link5/sublink6"><i class="fa fa-eye"></i><span class="hidden-sm">Sublink 6</span></a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
```

I am trying to set the anchor links background color on active click, but this doesn't seem to be working with `:a` because of the use of `#`. Any ideas?

Comment: Could you edit this to include some of the CSS styles you're trying to use?

Comment: I meant `:active`, not `:a`. I'm using `.nav-collapse a:active{
    background-color: red;
}` to set the active link to a color, but its not staying.

Comment: This seems to work just fine for me, see http://jsfiddle.net/738fW/2/ . Do you have any Javascript that could be listening for (and preventing) the handling of the onmousedown event? This would be my next guess as to what is going on.